# I substantially edited a question that was wrongly marked as duplicate, is it OK?

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions

This is the question - [Whitelisting and subdirectories in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/whitelisting-and-subdirectories-in-git).

The guy's problem was how whitelists don't work for subdirs if done naively, and it was marked as duplicate of [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files).

This becomes obvious only in the comments below, however.

I edited the question rather heavily, and marked it for reopen, is it OK? I mean the editing, it is more like a re-telling of the question, though it preserves the original intention of the asker.

Comment: If you're editing based on OP comments then it seems fair enough

Comment: Yes, the comments are below, he wasn't aware the problem was because of sub-dirs when he first wrote it. May be I should edit the answer, too, as it now quotes parts of the question that are not there at all!

Comment: Since this is an old question with several answers, including one being accepted, as long as you didn't invalidate any of the existing answers, you should be fine since it was based on his comments.

Comment: @satuon I am not familiar to know, but does the accept answer (and the other upvoted questions) still answer the post, and it is just the quotes in the answer that are problem?  If so, then editing the quotes out is probably acceptable as long as they don't change the answer.  However, if you can't edit them out without significant rewriting the answert, just leave them there and maybe leave a comment for the answerer

Comment: Yes, definitely, they still are relevant. I think that the question is pretty good now. It's still marked as duplicate, but I removed the link (it was in the question's body), since it was wrong.